# In Firestore using the Flutter SDK, is there a way to only add a field if the value of a variable is not null?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

If I have this code:

```
String? comment;

dbRef.collection('cities').add({
  'name': 'Boston',
  'comment': comment,
});
```

Is there a way to only set the field if `comment` is not null? As written above, it will create the `comment` field and set it to `null`. I know when using `update` for a document you can set `FieldValue.delete()`, but the docs say that is only for updating a document or using `set` with `merge: true`. Is there an equivalent when using `add`?

The reason for this is I'm assuming the field name and null value will still occupy space in the database, and if it's a field that will be empty most of the time, there is no sense in wasting the space by creating the field.

Comment: You can build the object first any way you want using a variable, then pass it to `add()`.  You don't have to build it within the call.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if it can be done within the call - with `update` you could do `'comment': comment != null ? comment : FieldValue.delete(),`.

Comment: If that's your requirement for this task, then you should state that in the question. Firestore doesn't have a way of saying "this property has no value, so leave it out". It will be on dart to provide a syntax for conditionally specifying a property inline, and I doubt it will be possible.